# Auto fit column length in xlsxwriter

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

I am try below code to find the max length of the columns and adjust its width accordingly but am getting error stating:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae'
in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Below is my code:

```
# Iterate through each column and set the width == the max
# length in that column A padding length of 2 is also added
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns): 
    # Find length of column i    
    column_len = df1[col].astype(str).str.len().max()
    # Setting the length if the column header is larger than the
    # max column value length
    column_len = max(column_len, len(col)) + 2
    # Set the column length        
    worksheet.set_column(i, i, column_len)
```